# Horizontal alignment of <div> elements

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am new to CSS and am having trouble with  elements.

Situation:

- I have 3 of them, inside of a big one, which is meant to **fill** the screen.

Expected result:

- I would like them to be **next** to each other, as three **vertical** bars, with the middle one having a **fixed width** (1000px)
- The other two being changeable, depending on the full window size on the given screen.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="whole">
    <div class="left" />
    <div class="middle" />
    <div class="right" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.left {
    background-color: white;
}

div.middle {
    background-color: blue;
width: 1000px;
}

div.right {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with flex-box, easy like this: 
I Changed the 1000px to 300px for the demo:

```css
.whole
{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /*just for the demo:*/
  height: 100vh;
}

.whole .left,
.whole .right
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: silver;
}

.whole .middle
{
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
    <div class="left">
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
    </div>

    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display inline-flex on the whole div and play with media query for responsive. I also add a media query for example. if screen is less then or equal to 768px then whole div get width 100%.  Also you can set the middle div width 100% at media screen. Any question ask me in comment. :)

```css
.whole{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-flex;
}
div.left {
 background: white;
}

div.middle {
 background: blue;
 width: 1000px;
}

div.right {
 background: yellow;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  .whole{
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
 <div class="left">A</div>
 
 <div class="middle">B</div>

 <div class="right">C</div>
   </div>
```